# How to make chat api for android and iphone using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to make chat api for android and iphone using AWS ?

I am new to server background. I am using AWS server to my project.I just want make chat api for android and ios. What is step by step to make chat api in aws?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a Server approach then you can use the following product on Amazon EC2 to create a Popular XMPP server ([ejabbered](https://www.ejabberd.im/))

[EJabbered on AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00E8NPBIQ)

Nowadays going serverless is getting more common and would like you to look on this example with AWS Lambda

[Example : AWS Lambda Chat](https://github.com/cloudnative/lambda-chat)

Ask for more below in comments :)

Comment: Is there any other chat method for  android and ios?

Comment: These are some Chat Protocols List > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_protocols based on these you can configure your environment on AWS